# Mapping email claim from custom claims provider to sharepoint user email in profile

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wif, claims-based-identity

I have Sharepoint 2010 using as the only authentication method a custom claims provider. 
My custom claims provider has a email claim: 
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress

I set this parameter on theshareponit console (stsadmin) when configuring the provider:

*$map3 = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "EmailAddress" -SameAsIncoming*

I want to see this claims mapped to the Sharepoint user profile. 
That means that when I access the user profile (clicking on "my settings" on the logged user for example) I would like to see the email parameter. 
(I would like to see the claim as a SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Email)

At this moment, those parameters are not mapped.

Any tip / help with that?
I'm really trying lot of several things but I can't get it to work!..

Thanks!..

PnP

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're showing will only assign the mapping to a variable (`$map3`).  You also need to add that mapping to the trusted issuer:

```
$sp = Get-SPTrustedIdentityProvider –Name "YourSTS"

Add-SPClaimTypeMapping -Identity $map3 -TrustedIdentityTokenIssuer $sp
```

Here is some more info and examples:

- http://sharepintblog.com/2011/10/26/adding-additional-claims-to-a-trusted-identity-token-issuer/
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607816.aspx

**EDIT**: To then map the claims, you need to go to Central Administration -> Application Management -> User Profile Service Application -> Manage User Properties -> Edit the Desired User Property.

Finally, edit the mapping as shown below:

[image]

Here is more info:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262327.aspx

Comment: Hi!... Thanks for your answer. I really didn't ask for how to add new claims (I know how to do that) but how to map them in the sharepoint profile. I still didn't find that!..

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update!.. now it looks useful!.. I just try to access Central Administration -> Application Management -> User Profile Service Application but I can't. I activated the User Profile syncronization service (it was stopped). Now it is started but still, I can't see that options (I restarted the server / iis, etc). Any tip / clue?

Comment: Hi. I finally was able to configure user profile service. But what you did requires a "source data connection" on the sync services. I can't create that connection, as it doesn't let me do it just using a regular custom claims provider.

Comment: Did you see this note: "Note: The selection of directory service properties may be disabled if the User Profile Service Application is in an untrusted domain or if profile synchronization is not configured." Did you try configuring the profile sync and still nothing?

Comment: Hi. Everything is working. But I just have an STS, not an AD or related user repository. So I don't have the option to synchronize!... and that's basically what I've been asking... how can I do it if I can't sync as it's not configurable. Thanks!